Metaphysical (Hard) Solipsism vs Epistemological (Soft) Solipsism
I’ve seen these terms tossed around as if they are actually different things but it does not appear to me that they are different philosophical positions/beliefs.
Perhaps I am wrong, but here is my definition of each
Metaphysical Solipsism: The only existents are (what I am arbitrarily terming) these (current(yet another arbitrary term)) cognitions.
Epistemological Solipsism: Any description about these cognitions other than that they do indeed exist are unfalsifiable assumptions. Therefore, to remain within the realm of certainty, one can only state the proposition There is something, this something being whatever this is, which we arbitrarily call ‘my cognitions’.

So whats the question?

If my understanding of the positions are correct?

[I have nothing [right now] to say to the question, but] I suggest you mean ontological when you say metaphysical

Yes precisely @Rushi

Just noticed you're the same who recently asked on Descartes. You may want to see this older answer. And here

From wiki, Metaphysical solipsism differs from Epistemological solipsism in that, Metaphysical Solipsism, and therefore one adhering to it as a position, states that nothing exists externally to this one mind, while Epistemological Solipsism, states that nothing can be known for certain to exist externally to this one mind.
